# How to run a javascript function onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

http://8animetv.co.vu/
Basically my problem is that when I open a post link on its own it just loads an ugly site. What this site does is that it loads the video posts to the right in a list and when you click on the video title it loads the post into the iframe to the left (where the picture is).

```
<iframe name="ifrm" id="ifrm" src="SomePicture.png"></iframe>
<ul>
    <li><a href="postLink" target="ifrm">Video 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

The post site and the main site is on the same html file. I need a function that whenever the window.location.href = homepage/post/something
it will instead go to http://8animetv.co.vu/ but load the homepage/post/something to the iframe. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just bind the function to onload event.
    
        window.onload=function(){};
    
To load a site to iframe you want to use the src property of iframe object. ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_frame.asp

Comment: My basic problem here is the fact that I don't know how to do the if statement. It should be something like: function postFunction() { if (windows.location.href = http://8animetv.co.vu/post/Anything else/) Then run the function.
How can I add a parameter that checks if the link is any sublink of /post ? Kinda hard to explain...

Comment: I think so! This will basically run a function if the link is anything like http://8anime.co.vu/post/blahblahblah/blahblahblah etc. else run something else?

Comment: p.s. I guess it should be window.location and not windows.location, right?